# How to stop a goroutine that is listening for RethinkDB changefeeds?

Tags: go, rethinkdb, goroutine

I am trying to figure out how to use RethinkDB changefeeds with golang.
My specific question is how to stop a goroutine that listens for changes to the
database. See, for example, the function `getData()` below. I run this from a handler
function by calling `go getData(c)`. Whenever the database updates, the record is
passed to the channel `c`, which is then passed to the handler function and sent to the client
using SSE technology. My question is: when the client disconnects, I know how to stop and exit
the handler function; however the goroutine that is running the `getData()` function, keeps running. What can
I do to close it? One solution I can think of based on other answers on stackoverflow is to
send a signal to close the goroutine on another channel and use a select statement to handle this
signal. For example, I can replace

```
    for cur.Next(&rec) {
        c <- rec
    }
```

in the function definition below with:

```
    for cur.Next(&rec) {
        select {
         case <- closesignal:
            return
         default:
            c <- rec
        }
    }
```

where, `closesignal` is another channel that is given as a third argument to `getData()` and
a message is sent on this channel by the handler when the client disconnects.

The problem with this approach is: what if the result of the specific rethinkdb query
never updates. In that case, the `for cur.Next(&rec)` loop will not be entered and the `closesignal` will not be used.
Would this goroutine then keep running? If so, how do I stop this goroutine?

**The `getData()` function**

```
func getData(session *r.Session, c chan interface{}) {
    var rec interface{}

    changesOpts := r.ChangesOpts{
        IncludeInitial: true,
    }

    cur, err := r.DB(DBNAME).Table("test").Changes(changesOpts).Run(session)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer cur.Close()

    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("exiting getData goroutine()...")
    }()


    for cur.Next(&rec) {
        c <- rec
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop a goroutine that is listening to a changefeed by closing the cursor. For example this code will listen to a changefeed for 10 seconds before closing:

```
go func() {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    cur.Close()
}()

for cur.Next(&rec) {
    c <- rec
}

// Loop exits as the cursor has been closed
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that helps. Are you the same Daniel Cannon who has written gorethink. If so, thanks a ton. It is an awesome library.

Comment: Great, glad its working now :) (and yes I did write GoRethink thanks! If you have any other questions feel free to get in touch on the RethinkDB slack)

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the changefeed via [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context). You can pass your context to the `RunOpts`. This will close your changefeed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to manage this situation is using [contexts](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) to close the cursor, with a goroutine.
Here some [good documentation from the go blog](https://blog.golang.org/context) about contexts.

Here it's an example of the implementation with context:

```
func AreThereChanges(ctx context.Context) error {
    cursor, err := r.Table("something").
        Changes().
        Run(db.Session)

    if err != nil {
      //manage error
    }

    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        <-ctx.Done()
        cursor.Close()
    }(ctx)

    var changeFeed map[string]interface{}
    for cursor.Next(&changeFeed) {
        if changeFeed["old_val"] != nil {
          //do something
        }

        if changeFeed["new_val"] != nil {
          //do something
        }
    }
```